# how to detect eventfd file descriptor close by other program

Tags: c++, linux

I have a client/server communicate through eventfd. If either client or server call `close(fd)` I would like the other end to find out (like file descriptor is closed now). I tried to use `select` with non-zero timeout, it always return 0 which is timeout. I saw people suggesting use `fcntl` it doesn't seems to be working either. Any suggestions?

Addtion Details (omitted non important part code, you can see [here for how to exchange file descriptor detail code](http://keithp.com/blogs/fd-passing/):
It is multi processes application. Server process created eventfd by calling

```
 struct msghdr control_message;
 int fd = eventfd(0,0);
 *CMSG_DATA(control_message) = fd;
 message.msg_control = &control_message;
 sendmsg(socket_fd, & message,0); //send this to client
```

From client side:

```
 recvmsg(socket_fd, & message,0);
 //loop using CMSG_NXTHDR(&message, control_message)
 int fd = *(int *) CMSG_DATA(contro_message);
```

Then on server side:

```
 close(fd);
```

On Client side:
     int rc;
     rc = dup2(fd,fd);

rc is never invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for a closed file descriptor?  How about this?

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void checkit ()
{
    int     rc;

    rc = dup2(2, 2);

    if ( rc == -1 )
            printf("error %d on dup2(2, 2): %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    else
            printf("dup2 successful\n");

    write(2, "still working\n", 14);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int     rc;

    checkit();

    close(2);

    checkit();

    return  0;
}
```

Running it generates this output:

```
dup2 successful
still working
error 9 on dup2(2, 2): Bad file descriptor
```

If this is a multi-threaded application using poll and you want poll to return when the file descriptor is closed by another thread, POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL might help.

**Multi-Threaded Version using Poll**

And here's a sample that shows how to detect a closed fd with poll (POLLNVAL is the event) in a multi-threaded program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void *run_poll (void *arg)
{
    struct pollfd   fds[1];
    int             rc;

    fds[0].fd = 2;
    fds[0].events = POLLERR | POLLHUP | POLLNVAL;

            //
            // Poll indefinitely
            //

    printf("starting poll\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    rc = poll((struct pollfd *) &fds, 1, -1);

    if ( rc == -1 )
    {
            printf("POLL returned error %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
            printf("POLL returned %d (revents = 0x%08x): %s %s %s\n",
                   rc,
                   fds[0].revents,
                   ( ( fds[0].revents & POLLERR  ) ? "pollerr" : "noerr" ),
                   ( ( fds[0].revents & POLLHUP  ) ? "pollhup" : "nohup" ),
                   ( ( fds[0].revents & POLLNVAL ) ? "pollnval" : "nonval" ));
    }

    return  NULL;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t       thread;
    int             rc;

    rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, run_poll, NULL);

    usleep(100);
    printf("closing stderr\n");
    close(2);
    usleep(100);

    return  0;
}
```

This generates the output

```
starting poll
closing stderr
POLL returned 1 (revents = 0x00000020): noerr nohup pollnval
```

Comment: BTW, errno EBADF is "Bad file descriptor".

Comment: You used a well know fd (stderr). I used fd returned by  `eventfd(0,0)`. I also have 2 processes in stead multithread. What I have found is that file descriptor opened in server passed to the client becomes in-valid (even numeric value is the same). I used your dup2 trick it returns negative value (errno 9, invalid file descriptor).

Comment: That's correct - file-descriptors are specific to the process that opens them.  In fact, 0, 1, and 2 are always stdin, stdout and stderr of the process - so you can see how they would not be easy to share.

Comment: It's generally not possible to open a file in one process and access it in another process.  Can you explain the use case?  I might be able to help solve it.

Comment: I just updated my question since it is easier to format in the question than in comments. Can you check it out? Thanks.

Comment: @user2532621: File descriptors can be shared rather easily between threads in a process, or with a forked child, or by passing a file descriptor over a UNIX domain socket. Indeed, this is one of the primary intended use cases for an eventfd. The question here is how to detect when the *other* instance of an eventfd was closed, not the local one.

Comment: @duskwuff - I will refine my statement.  It is not possible to open a file in one process and access it another process that is not a child of the original process created after the file is opened.  By saying that it's possible to send a file descriptor over a socket, it gives the impression that file descriptors are global, but they are process-specific.  That's why every process has 0, 1 and 2 but not every process shares the same standard input, standard output, and standard error files.  With that said, I'm not familiar with eventfd; I'll check it.

Comment: @user2426361 - why use eventfd() to communicate between the server and client?  They already have a socket open that allows communication, right?  Or, is there some other intent to the code?

Comment: @user2532621: Incorrect. It **is** possible to pass a file descriptor across processes, outside of a parent/child relationship, using a `SCM_RIGHTS` message across a UNIX domain socket. The process receiving the file descriptor ends up with a copy of the original, just as if it had been inherited across `fork()`.

Comment: @user2532621 domain socket is just used for initial fd transmitting, after that the communication is strictly using eventfd which is light weight communication, that is what eventfd was designed for.

Comment: @user2426361 - I see.  What is the need to detect when the server has closed the eventfd?  It looks like eventfd may not support such detection.  For fast communication, traditionally SYSV IPCs (shared memory and sempahores or message queues) were used.  I wonder just how much faster (lighter) eventfd is over a pipe or unix domain socket.

Comment: @duskwuff - as, I see. It's a newer Linux feature in Linux with which I am unfamiliar - nice.  Still, technically, the file descriptor isn't being shared or passed because, as previously stated, the descriptors themselves are specific to individual processes.  Another way to describe this is that a process can pass open file, by descriptor, to another process with SCM_RIGHTS which allocates a new file descriptor in the target, receiving process.  I wonder what happens when the receiving process doesn't want the file descriptor; I also wonder about security risks this may raise.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2532621 it might be eventfd implementation doesn't support this detection at all so this question might have no answer. Eventfd is nice that it can be multiplex with other sources using select/poll while shmem/lock couldn't. You can read notes section of eventfd manual regarding pipe vs eventfd from [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)